# Need help XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Want to Split the word using XSLT

Input is

```
<ID>ABCD-1234-6547</ID>
```

and the output should look like

```
<ID>ABCD-1234</ID>
```

I want XSLT code for the above-summarized problem.

I did not write code yet.

The output should look like

```
<ID>ABCD-1234</ID>
```

Comment: An example is not enough; you need to explain the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="tokenize(ID, '-')[position() le 2]" separator="-"/>
```

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGcF/1

---

Or perhaps it's sufficient to do simply:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="substring(ID, 1, 9)"/>
```

Comment: This worked Perfectly thank you very much, Michael.
<xsl:value-of select="tokenize(ID, '-')[position() le 2]" separator="-"/>